# list of folder from source folders to destination folders copy vba

Tags: excel, vba, directory, file-management

I have list of folder list as source path and destination path
I tried to use below codes but cannot understand how to loop in list as below one by one. I need to delete destination folders first, then copy from source folder.

```
c:\a
c:\b
c:\c
```

to

```
D:\a
D:\b
d:\c
```

Code:

```
Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()
    'This example copy all Excel files from FromPath to ToPath.
    'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
    'existing files in this folder
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    FileExt = "*.xl*"  '<< Change
    'You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for Word files

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've copied in from Ron de Bruin's Excel Automation site really deals with a whole folder. What I expect you're looking for is a loop to provide a wrapper, which provides access to the individual sub-folder first. Then you can use the code above and add your delete logic, etc. Try this (I use early binding so add reference to script library if you don't already have it.):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyFolders(SourceFolderName As String)

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Folder
    Dim SourceSubFolder As Folder
    
    Set SourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
    For Each SourceSubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
        
        ' UPDATE AND PUT YOUR CODE TO COPY SPECIFIC FOLDERS IN HERE
        Debug.Print SourceSubFolder.Name
        
    Next

End Sub
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subfolders-property